# Selectively deleting commas and splitting strings

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I have s string that looks like

```
txt = '"EMB","iShares J,P. Morg",110.81,N/A'
```

I'm using `strsplit(txt,',');` to break this into separate strings based on the comma delimiter. However I want to ignore the comma between the `'J'` and the `'P'`, since it's not a delimiter; it's just part of the name.

Is there a way I can say "if a comma is between two quotes but there are other characters between the quotes, delete the comma"?

Comment: Wait for someone who knows regex well, I'm sure there is.

Comment: Thanks Hugh! I'll look at regex in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A silly (but functional) answer:

```
inquotes=false;
keep=true(1,length(txt));
for v=1:length(txt)
    if (txt(v)=='"')
        inquotes=~inquotes;
    elseif (txt(v)==',' && inquotes)
        keep(v)=false;
    end
end
txt=txt(keep);
tt=strsplit(txt,',');
```

This will, if you are in quotes, remove the commas so that you can use strsplit. That is what I understood you want to do, correct?

Comment: That is what I want to do; for some reason I'm getting an 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions' error.

Comment: Glad it does! Just be careful if using it; if there is a stray doublequote anywhere it will mess it all up!

Comment: This may well be much faster than Matlab's slow `regexp`, provided one has `strsplit`, which is new to Matlab as of R2013a (finally).

Comment: You can use `textscan` with comma delimiters and empty whitespace arguments to do the same in earlier versions - `strsplit = @(x,y) textscan(x,'%s','delimiter',y,'whitespace','');`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an equivalent `regexp` one-liner:

```
C = regexp(txt, '("[^"]*")|([^,"]+)', 'match')
```

The result is a cell array with already split strings. Unfortunately, I don't have MATLAB R2013, so I cannot benchmark this versus `strsplit`.